# Would derating a 25 amp breaker be safe for a 20 amp circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle, appliances

I'm wondering if I can use a 25 amp breaker on a twenty amp receptacle  after my 80% derate or grouping which would put me at 20 amps on #  10 thhn

Comment: Any reason not to just use a common 20 amp breaker and not worry about it?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a 20A receptacle for a 25A load, which is what "20A after derate" **is.** You either need to break the unspecified load up into two smaller loads, or hardwire, 10AWG wire, and a 25A breaker.

If your load needs a 25A breaker, your wire needs to be good for 25A

Comment: Nec 310.15(b)(2)(a)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Negative, Ghost Rider.  A 20A receptacle can only be on a 20A circuit meaning 20A breaker.

There is no 80% derate.  There is a 125% derate for certain loads - meaning the circuit, plug, etc. must be rated for 125% of the actual ampacity.  But this applies to all points including breaker, plug, socket and wires.  Unrelated:

> 210.23(A)(1) The rating of any one cord-and-plug connected equipment not fastened in place shall not exceed 80% of the branch-circuit ampere rating.

Okay, there is an 80% rule but it's not a derate.

For instance say you have an 18 amp heater.  The heater gets a 125% derate to 22.5 amps.  As such it cannot use a 20A plug because 22.5 > 20.  If it's going to be cord-and-plug, it must go to the next size of plug, which is 30A.    Now revisit 210.21(B)(3) and what breaker sizes can you have on a 30A socket? 30A only.